# parse-server - import mysql data

Tags: mysql, parse-server

I have a existing mysql database and was going to switch to parse-server, is there anything in their system for importing data from say CSV or another format?  I don't see anything in the interface directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing built into parse-server for importing; however, scripting it should be pretty straightforward.

parse-server maintains info about the mongo schema in a system collection `_SCHEMA` and also maintains collections to describe certain types of relationships between objects.  Because of this, you want to use one of the SDK's (i.e. php, javascript, etc.) to perform the import so that the parse-server can setup these tables for you.

so if you had three tables in mysql: author, books, and book_author, you'd do something like:

1. Iterate through each book and create a parse `Book` object for each.  Depending on the number you could either save them one by one, or you could save them in batches of, say 100.
2. Iterate through each author and create parse `Author` for each
3. Iterate through each book_author, look up the `book` for each, look up the `author` and add the author to the `authors` array on your `book` object